# Фильтрация js в webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Доброго времени суток.
Интересует, возможно ли, так сказать, в режиме реального времени включать/выключать выполнение js через webview. Т.к. Если отключить js изначально, то нужную страницу он не загружает, просто белый лист, а если включить, то он ее загрузит, но после того как я нажму на сайте "далее", будет подгружена следующая страница, на которой мне уже надо отключить js.
Вопрос такой: возможно ли динамически отключать/включать js или возможно ли выполнять только определенные js? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Унаследовать класс от WebView и переопределить метод onPageFinished вот таким образом:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
    if (url.contains("АДРЕС_НУЖНОЙ_СТРАНИЦЫ")) {
         webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    }
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
}
```

Comment: Т.е. получается, что мне придется перезагружать страницу? Или они отключатся до загрузки страницы?

Comment: Они отключатся после загрузки страницы. Вместо АДРЕС_НУЖНОЙ_СТРАНИЦЫ - вставляете адрес страницы, на которой нужно отключить JS. Ну, или !url.contains... , если для всех, кроме определенной

Comment: а возможно просто взять и не загружая сайт, исполнить определенные скрипты с него? Ну, скажем, это фиксированные js, но нужны не все, возможно просто взять и прописать какие скрипты надо исполнять и все? А те, что не надо, соответственно, не прописывать и не исполнять. Грубо говоря, отфильтровать